# Talend ESB pass variable into cTalendJob from Route

Tags: integration, esb, talend

How I can set `exchange.getIn().getMessageId()` in to variable and pass it through `ContextParam` in `cTalendJob` to my Job?  I can pass String like "bla bla bla", but when I try pass variable like 
`

```
${myVariable}, 
 #{myVariable}, 
 {myVariable}, 
 $myVariable, 
 context.myVariable
```

I get error myVariable cannot be resolved a variable.

Someone knows how to do it?

Comment: Problem on Talend Forum: https://www.talendforge.org/forum/viewtopic.php?id=48951

Answer (score 0):

You can get a variable in a job from a route with the configuration of `tRouteInput`.
In the `tRouteInput` write somethings like that:

```
${header.typesOfParametre.nameOfParametre}
```

header if you put the variable in the header...

I hope i helped you

Answer (score 0):

If, like me, you didn't want to change the `tRouteInput` component of your job, but just set a context parameter for the job from `${myvariable}` in your route, then there is a slightly ugly way of doing it.

I wanted to set the context parameter from a message header, so I created a `cSetHeader` component and set a header matching the context parameter name, which allows you to select the expression language and therefore in simple you can have `${header.headerName}`.

In the "Advanced Settings" tab of `cTalendJob`, select the "Propagate Header" checkbox and this will populate any context variables that exactly match the name of the message headers.

This has worked for me, but for completeness and safety, you might want to make sure you strip any headers you *don't* need in case they overwrite other context variables in the Talend job.